# Message Queue with AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs, amazon-sns

Im writing an app using the AWS framework. It would be the perfect framework if the SQS had FIFO access!

I am using SNS to publish messages to queues, and the order of the messages is important. Does anyone know of a MQ that can be used, that is scalable etc.. like SQS that can be used?

I have been looking at using ironMQ but the SNS seems to have issues with receiving the messages?

(or even better yet,if you know of a good way of ordering messages with SQS)

Thanks,
Ben

Comment: Dup, see [amazon sqs :read message not in order][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10876441/

Comment: What are the issues with IronMQ and SNS?  Maybe we can help you resolve that.

Comment: Since SQS is distributed, there is no FIFO because _"first-in to where?"_

Answer (score 3):

These days, [Amazon Kinesis](https://aws.amazon.com/kinesis/) would be a good choice. (It wasn't available when the question was raised.)

Kinesis captures data in streams, retains order and allows the data to be replayed and even consumed by multiple applications.